# Additional Parameter in array callback

Tags: node.js

I try to log a foreach callback to a file inside my node app. I try to use:

```
    var logger = fs.createWriteStream('tests/temp.js', {
        flags: 'a' 
    })

    req.body.selection.forEach(myFunction(logger));

    logger.end() // close string
```

In the callback I try:

```
function myFunction(mylogger,postvalue) {
    Object.entries(myJsonData.testCases).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if(postvalue == key){
            console.log("gefunden");
            mylogger.write('some data') // append string to your file
        }
    });
}
```

But this is wrong. Anyone can help me t find the brainbreak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest passing an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which propagates both the logger and the callback argument to the destination:

```
req.body.selection.forEach((value) => myFunction(logger, value));
```